# How to create a forwarding server in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want to create a program to forward data from 1 TCP socket to another and vice versa.Two different programs are connected to my server and want communicate through my server.

Actually I want two games to commincate via my server.so i want to create a server which will look transperant to players of the game,it will just forward whatever comes from one side to the other.

Comment: k here you go http://pastebin.com/1R7yUqVg

Comment: and http://pastebin.com/bMZ5Vcsk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what your problem was, but I'll take a guess. You read content into a buffer, and if you get any content you write the whole buffer to the output stream. You should only write the number of bytes that was actually read.

```
byte[] b = new byte[BUFSIZE];
int chunkSize;
while(true) {
  try {
    while( (chunkSize = is.read(b)) != -1) {
      os.write(b, 0, chunkSize);
      os.flush();
    }
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(socketProducer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```